# Swift 3 / Xcode / Firebase - can't access nested Array in TableView - numberOfRowsInSection

Tags: multidimensional-array, firebase, tableview, swift3, xcode8

I'm downloading my data from Firebase, and something is going wrong when I'm assembling my nested array so that I can't access it in the numberOfRowsInSection function.  I know this because when I hard code my array everything works fine.

This is the array I am dealing with, it contains Tasks and Deficiencies:

```
[["Plumbing", "Floors"],["Paint Scratched", "Missing Tile"]]
```

This is how it's created:

```
var tasksArray = [String]()
var deficienciesArray = [String]()
var masterArray = [[String]]()


let dbref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
    dbref.child("Inspections").child(outstandingTasks[0].jobNo).observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        self.masterArray.removeAll()
        self.tasksArray.removeAll()
        self.deficienciesArray.removeAll()

        for item in snapshot.children {
            var fireItem = (snapshot: item as! FIRDataSnapshot)
                if fireItem.key == "tasks"{
                    for item in fireItem.children{
                        let snap = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
                        self.tasksArray.append(snap.value as! String)
                    }
                }else if fireItem.key == "deficiencies"{
                    for item in fireItem.children{
                        let snap = item as! FIRDataSnapshot
                        self.deficienciesArray.append(snap.value as! String)
                    }
                }
        }                
        self.masterArray.append(self.tasksArray)
        self.masterArray.append(self.deficienciesArray)

        self.tableView.reloadData()

        })
     }
```

This is where it fails:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return masterArray[section].count
}
```

This is my error:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

What is further puzzling to me, is this code works:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        cell.textLabel?.text = masterArray[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] as! String
        return cell
    }
```

Comment: Please include how you implemented `numberOfSectionsInTableView:`. If you didn't implement it at all, there's your answer: `masterArray` has `0` items, while the default number of sections is `1`. Also, the debugger is your friend, use it.

Comment: @vzsg I have `numberOfSectionsInTableView ` set for 2.  As I mentioned, everything works when I hard code the masterArray so the issue must be in building my masterArray.  I would say the debugger is certainly not my friend right now ;) as the only discernible information is "fatal error: Index out of range"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have numberOfSectionsInTableView set for 2. (from your comment)

And there you have it. Before the Firebase has a chance to download the current items, your `masterArray` variable is an empty array.

As your implementation of `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` does not check anything and tries to subscript the array, it explodes right away because `masterArray[0]` is an invalid index.

You should implement `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` in a smarter way to handle this:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return masterArray.count
}
```